# In what case does jQuery sortable fail silently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-1.10

I've been trying to see why a certain jQuery `.sortable()` will not enable any drag/drop events in some circumstances - In a certain jQuery dialog I have a sortable, I confirm that the element exists while debugging (`$('theelement')` is length 1, just before calling `$('theelement').sortable()`).

I verify the events are there, with Chrome's inspector, and I can't see any reason it wouldn't be doing the exact same code that is working in another jQuery dialog, in which allows drag-drop reordering. I've removed classes of the container to make it similar to the one in which it works, in case something like `jQuery('.something theelement').mouseup(function(){return false})` is firing.

I've also simplified the code by changing the sortable to something as simple as

```
<ul target element>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

and calling `jquery(target element).sortable()` so it shouldn't be some complex css or dom issue causing this.

Is there anything other than debugging each step through each line of the minified jQuery-ui source, to find the source of this problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you attach another ui method like `.draggable()` to the target element, does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, draggable() does work. So does removing the function with `jQuery(element).data('uiSortable','')` before adding sortable again. adding ':visible' to the jquery input also prevents the whole problem of corrupting the element somehow when that was called before it was shown, which was preventing it from ever working.